# Smarty fetch is not working

Tags: php, smarty3

I am having issues with smarty "fetch".Its not loading the content.I have checking a found where i have found

```
$subject = $smarty->fetch("emailtpl:emailsubject");
    $message = $smarty->fetch("emailtpl:emailmessage");
```

When i try to print the $subject and $message variables, they are comming blank. I am trying to understand the issue. Please help. The code is :-

```
#$subject :- This variable has value like "forgot password"
    #$message :- This variable has value like email content

    include_once(ROOTDIR . "/includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php");
        $smarty = new Smarty();
        $smarty->caching = 0;
        $smarty->compile_dir = ROOTDIR . "/" . $templatecompilerpath;
        $smarty->compile_id = md5($subject . $message);
        $smarty->register_resource("emailtpl", array( "emailtpl_template", "emailtpl_timestamp", "emailtpl_secure", "emailtpl_trusted" ));
        $smarty->assign("emailsubject", $subject);
        $smarty->assign("emailmessage", $message);


#It assigns value 
$smarty->assign("enc", $enc);       //enc is vaiable having vluae defined


Then it takes the value as


$subject = $smarty->fetch("emailtpl:emailsubject");
    $message = $smarty->fetch("emailtpl:emailmessage");
```

But when i print the  $subject and $message variables. They are blank. I didnt understand , how this code is working and where emailtpl define.

How to debug it. Please help

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work. Fetch is used to save the output in a variable.

And fetch needs a Template File. This template file will be filled with your assigns and after fetching saved in $subject.

Btw. what exactly do you wanna do with this code?!